# numPartitions for reduceByKey not affecting speed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, spark-streaming

I'm receiving time series data, and want to persist/upsert only the most recent entry we get based on a specific key.  We used to be aggregating things with `mapWithState` and we were able to process about 1k/sec locally around 6k/sec on our qa environment, and around 45k/sec on our beefiest environments.

I removed a lot of code, because we had some requirement changes and I think the reason I'm seeing such slow behavior is because of `reduceByKey` here's a small amount of code I have:

```
rawStream
    .map(timeSeries => (timeSeries.key, AggregationEngine.createSingleItemAggregate(timeSeries)))
    // Select the last value for the key
    .reduceByKey((accumulator: AggregationResult, aggregationResult: AggregationResult) => {
        if (accumulator.firstTimeMillis > aggregationResult.firstTimeMillis) {
            accumulator
        } else {
            aggregationResult
        }
    }, numPartitions = numberOfReduceTasks)
    // Send back table name and aggregate
    .map(aggResultPair => (aggResultPair._2.tableName, aggResultPair._2) )
```

This takes about 3-5 minutes to proccess 500 data points locally, and it's pretty slow on small batch sizes on our qa environment.  I understand that there should be a slow down with it, because before everything was one stage, now because of the shuffling, it's broken into two stages, and shuffling takes a long time. Is there an ideal `numPartitions` value that I should be using? Like maybe each core should add X partitions, or per gig of memory you should add X more partitions.  I've been running it locally, and trying to figure it out, but nothing really gets me to a reasonable processing time for this.

Comment: general recommendation, num partitions > num of cores . try, num partitions = 2* cores. Try to see in spark UI whether the data is equally distributed or not .

Comment: Alright, you think though that it's normal to see such a performance hit like this though?

Comment: Repartitioning results in a shuffle which in-turn generally causes data transfer over network, which impacts the performance in a major way. You can read this ( http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/ ) article and decide based on you Spark configuration and cluster specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar experience with Spark on a small cluster with around 2000 items in an RDD. Repartitioning to many different partition counts did not make a difference. Once I ran it with more items (around 4000 but I think this depends on the number of executors you have) it started behaving as expected. Try running it with more data points.

Comment: I think I kinda noticed that.  I'll try and actually verify that, and then I'll come back and accept the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to verify? What results did you get?

Comment: Ya, it took 5s to process 19k events on a 4 executors, and 3s to process 1.5k events.